# Why is {entry_date} outputting incorrect date?

Tags: expressionengine

I'm having a really strange issue in two templates pulling from the same channel in which the {entry_date} variable is alternately outputting either today's date or tomorrow's date for every entry it lists, depending on which template I'm viewing.

I have verified that there are in fact proper separate entry dates for each of these entries in the back end, and the channel:entries tag is properly outputting the entries in descending order by date, but for whatever reason the actual date shown via the {entry_date} tag is not correct.

For example, every single entry is currently showing a date of "09/30/2012", despite the fact that the entries were made on various dates between the 24th and today.

I'm a bit puzzled as to what may be causing this behavior, as it's the first time I've ever run into the issue after having built a good 12 or so sites based on EE.

I am logged in as Admin, which I don't *think* should be causing problems, but I thought it was worth mentioning. Here's a sample of the relevant template code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="orders" limit="30" dynamic="no" author_id="CURRENT_USER" status="open|closed|Completed" orderby="date" sort="desc" show_future_entries="no" }
    <tr>
        <td class="date">{entry_date format="%m/%t/%Y"}</td>
        <td class="orderid"><a href="{path={template_group}/invoice}/{entry_id}">{title}</a></td>
        <td class="total">{order_total}</td>
    </tr>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your {entry_date} tag, you have %t, which outputs the number of days in a month. I believe you want either %d or %D, one has a leading zero and the other does not.

So, in other words, it isn't showing the entry as having been posted on September 30th, just that there are 30 days in September.

Comment: And there's me being a complete bonehead and overlooking something simple. Thanks!